# MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of TAG command

Tags: imacros

I'm not a programer, but I need to run this script for bot. Can someone help me figure out?

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*60 + 1); randomNumber;")
TAB T=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>VIDEO" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>FORM>INPUT:nth-of-type(4)" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=commments.com
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT EXTRACT=TXT
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:comment_sent ATTR=ID:comment CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:comment_sent ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR2}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>A" BUTTON=0
```

Error:

```
Error in line 16 : TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT EXTRACT=TXT
```

Comment: It would be better if you could give more details. Run where? What environment? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because, the attribute (`ATTR`) part of the line is wrong. It should be `ATTR=` followed by the attribute you want to watch, then a `:` followed by the content of the attribute.

So before it was:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT EXTRACT=TXT
```

And after correction it should be:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Note, how I have used, the wildcard (`*`) for allowing any kind of content inside of the HTML tag!

After doing so the code runs fine! Please let me know if this solves your issue!